# What is the command for Selenium Driver to click on the green check on the android keyboard for automated testing?

Tags: java, android, selenium, keyboard, appium

[Android Keyboard Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaMkM.png)

I'm doing automated testing to send a text. The app does not have a "submit" button but rather by clicking the green check of the android keyboard, it will submit the text. UIAUTOMATORVIEWER does not show the element or any form of id when it comes to the android keyboard.

Thing's that I have tried is:

```
driver.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
sendKeys(66) (66 = ENTER)
```

Comment: WHat do you mean green check of the android keyboard?  Do you mean the action button?  The default android keyboard has no green check, and many OEMs use custom keyboards including Samsung (Swiftkey based) and Huawei (Swype based).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For key events, you need to use `driver.pressKeyCode()`

So what you want is `driver.pressKeyCode(66)`. If you want it to be even more readable:
`driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER)`

Also keep in mind pressKeyCode only works for AndroidDriver.